# Capture freeform view controller screenshot in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to capture screenshot of entire scrollable view controller. Its freeform view controller with height of 1025. screenshot image should be entire screen of 1045 OR scrollview frame.[image: screen height]

i have tried this code but it capture only visible rect. I want screenshot of entire view under the scroll view

```
fileprivate extension UIScrollView {
func screenshot() -> UIImage? {
    // begin image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contentSize, false, 0.0)
    // save the orginal offset & frame 
    let savedContentOffset = contentOffset
    let savedFrame = frame
    // end ctx, restore offset & frame before returning
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        contentOffset = savedContentOffset
        frame = savedFrame
    }
    // change the offset & frame so as to include all content
    contentOffset = .zero
    frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height)
    guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    layer.render(in: ctx)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    return image
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `layer.render` triggers layoutSubviews and resets your frame.

As we don't want to loose all our constraints, we need to store them, disable for the time of screen capture, and turn them on again:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func screenshot() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contentSize, false, 0.0)
        // save the orginal offset, take a ref to all constraints related to the view
        let savedContentOffset = contentOffset
        let actualConstraints = relatedConstraints()
        // deactivate non needed constraints so they won't stop us from resiging scroll view
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(actualConstraints)
        // enable auth generated constraints based on the frame
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height)
        contentOffset = .zero
        defer {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            
            // reset original constraints
            translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(actualConstraints)
            
            // layout superview needed before resetting content offset
            superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            contentOffset = savedContentOffset
        }
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }
        layer.render(in: ctx)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        return image
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func relatedConstraints() -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        var constraints = self.constraints
        var parent = superview
        while parent != nil {
            constraints.append(contentsOf: parent!.constraints.filter { $0.firstItem === self || $0.secondItem === self })
            parent = parent!.superview
        }
        return constraints
    }
}
```